# Emacs doesn't load GUI

Tags: troubleshooting, ubuntu-10.04, emacs

Whenever I run *emacs* or *emacs23* on terminal I just get the following output:

```
** (emacs:2620): CRITICAL **: menu_proxy_module_load: assertion `dbusproxy != NULL' failed
```

And the GUI doesn't load, and emacs' window never opens. The emacs process doesn't actually crash (the terminal stays busy, and I can see the *emacs23* process running with *ps -e*).

I've tried running it with the *-D --debug-init* arguments, but the same thing happens and the output is exactly the same. However, if I run *emacs -nw* it successfully runs emacs in terminal mode as if nothing were wrong.

Strangely, this problem only started happening the second time I ran emacs today. The first time it worked perfectly fine. Since then, I've tried rebooting and I've tried purging the emacs installation, to no success.

I haven't installed any new packages today, but I might have upgraded some, could that be the reason? Is there a way to find out which packages were installed/upgraded today?

EDIT: Additionally, if I run *sudo emacs* it loads normally and everything runs great.

I'm running Ubuntu Lucid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you hit a known [Ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appmenu-gtk/+bug/593474) where the appmenu-gtk package seems to be broken. The solution seems to be to remove this package until this gets fixed in the repositories.

If this doesn't work don't run your emacs `sudo` like suggested by some people over there, rather use emacs on the command line with

```
$ emacs -nw
```

or use another editor for the time being.

My crystal ball tells me that this might get fixed not too far in the future.

Comment: @dconnors, @honk: a [comment on that bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appmenu-gtk/+bug/593474/comments/38) suggests the broken packages may be coming from the Unity PPA; if you have that PPA enabled, try disabling it and reinstalling the affected packages.

Comment: @quack quixote: That's possible, I think I installed the global menu applet from that PPA. I like this applet so much that I'm willing to wait a couple of weeks to see if they fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I installed `emacs25-lucid`, also make sure you install `xaw3dg` package as it's a dependency .